# How to Parse a value in a nested JSON using Postman

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying to parse the json response from post request and send the parsed data to put request this is my response body

```
    {
        "createdBy": "student",
        "createdOn": "2019-06-18",
        "Id1": "0e8b9445-4bd9-4d31",
        "Tl": [
            {
                "createdBy": "student",
                "createdOn": "2019-06-18",
                "Id2": "d46eeb88-f876-4468"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am parsing `id1` and `id2` which are auto generated. This is the code I am writing in tests

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Id1", jsonData.Id1);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Id2", jsonData.Tl[2].Id2);
```

`id1` is working but I am unable to access `Id2` and getting the error after post as

> typeerror cannot read Id2  property

and I am accessing Id2 in put request as `{{Id2}}`

Comment: `jsonData.Tl` has only one element so you should use `jsonData.Tl[0].Id2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking a value in a nested JSON using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42850233/checking-a-value-in-a-nested-json-using-postman)

Answer (score 1):

In the following statement, you are trying to access the 3rd element (index: 2) of the array with key 'Tl' :

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Id2", jsonData.Tl[2].Id2);
```

You should access the 1st element only (index:0) :

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Id2", jsonData.Tl[0].Id2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only one element in `jsonData.Tl` - so `jsonData.Tl[2]` is `undefined`. Use `jsonData.Tl[0]` to access the first element.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Id1", jsonData.Id1);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Id2", jsonData.Tl[2].Id2);
```

Comment: tried using same but i am getting error as typeerror cannot read Id2 property